# django string shows good in terminal but not in template

Tags: python, django, string, format

I am working on a message system but after i have sent a reply, my tempalte view of my mailbody gets put all on 1 line, while when i print the same string in terminal it works just fine.

The template:

```
<div>
To: {{ mail.to }}<br>
From: {{ mail.sender }}<br>
{{ mail.view_sent_at }}<br>
</div>

<div>
<br>
{{ mail.body }}
</div>
```

my reply body function:
(to change the body to be shown as replay)

```
def reply_format(self):
    message = self.body
    message = "> " + message
    message = message.replace("\r\n", "\r\n> ")
    send_information = "\r\n\r\n> To: %s\r\n> From: %s\r\n> Date: %s\r\n>\r\n" % (self.to, self.sender, self.view_sent_at())
    message = send_information + message
    return message
```

now as example my mail body looks like this when i save it (and how it looks in my terminal after).

```
Send a reply

> To: admin
> From: admin
> Date: 12:14 02-06-2014
>
> This is a test.
> Need some extra lines
> Byebye
```

when i open it in my template it looks like:

```
To: admin
From: admin
12:14 02-06-2014

Send a reply > To: admin > From: admin > Date: 12:14 02-06-2014 > > This is a test. > Need some extra lines > Byebye
```

Comment: Why are you surprised by that? If you're viewing it in an HTML page, you need to use HTML tags for linebreaks etc. As a plain text email, linebreaks are preserved.

Comment: so when saving my mail i should replace the \r\n by a <br> ? Because on the first mail it works fine, jsut after the reply it gets on 1 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [linebreaks filter](http://serk.io/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) in your template to convert the newlines to the appropriate HTML tags.